# .NET 3.5 Targeted Project has references with wrong version - 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I start a new C# Class Library project targeting .NET 3.5.  The resulting project has only 1 class - Class1.cs, and has 3 references ...

1. System
2. System.Data
3. System.Xml

... but each of these refer to the .NET 4.0 version.  After build, I examine the .dll file with ILDASM and find the resulting assembly is a .NET 4.0 version.

This just started today.  Yesterday, it was working as expected (where the 3 references were the .NET 2.0 version and the resulting .dll file was a 3.5 version).

What would cause this behavior?

*** UPDATE ***

I have uninstalled .NET 4.0 and uninstalled VS2010, then re-installed both.  Problem persists.  I think it may have something to do with CLR 2.0.  When adding a reference it shows a list of available assemblies filtered to CLR 2.0, but the list contains CLR 4.0 assemblies... Weird...  Have not been successful in removing and re-installing .NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.

*** FINAL UPDATE ***

Well, couldn't figure it out in a timely fashion, so I formatted and reinstalled everything including the OS.  That fixed it...

Comment: Are you using WebForms,WinForms,ASP.NET or DLL Projects where this is Class Library is referencing? Have you installed nuget packages to the Project? There could be several reasons why this is happening but i would start there. if not check the physical reference properteis in the IDE could be they got updated by mistake.

Comment: Hi Qpirate,  I am creating the most basic class library project.  It is not used by anything because it has no implementation within the class 'Class1'.  I am trying to identify why my IDE is working (how I would categorize as) incorrectly, and as such I am using the most basic example possible.  There is no use of NuGet.  - What do you mean by "Check the Physical Reference Properties in the IDE" - do you mean look for the reference file path?  If so, I have checked and it refers to the .NET 4 framework path.  These references are strong named and automatically defined.

Answer (score 0):

Project->Properties->Application->Target framework

Comment: Yeah, if I understand your answer correctly, your answer describes my problem - I have the project targeted to 3.5, yet it builds a 4.0.  There must be another switch somewhere that tells .NET to use well named references of a specific version.  Its like my target settings are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the references and re-add them, but make sure that when you are registering them back, check the `Targeting Framework` in the add reference dialog.

If it says 4.0 or 4.5 then your `.csproj` file is not registered correctly as 3.5 and you will need to fix that.

Try unloading and edit the project file. look for the following in the XML

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

change to 3.5 and reload. then clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: The TargetFrameworkVersion is already 3.5.  Removing and re-adding the references shows the 4.0 version not the 2.0 version as expected.  Definitely a hosed system.

Comment: Yeah it looks as if your solution is not registering your .net properly. I don't know how to fix it. Sorry.